# http basic auth for 2 sites

Tags: ruby, authentication, selenium, webdriver

there is a dilemma for me as I have 2 urls that I need to pass auth

```
url = http://admin:admin@url
url2 = https://admin:admin@url2



@driver.navigate.to url2
@driver.navigate.to url
```

when I execute selenium script, I am trying to pass url2 and then url as to get auth remembered. Just have 2 redirects and there is no way around that.
So dilemma is that
url2 http I still get auth window to enter credentials, but url that goes through just fine.
Is there anything else can be done?
I am using Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, if your URLs use a cookie for authentication, you can generate the cookie value beforehand and set it to the cookie.

```
require "selenium-webdriver"
require "awesome_print"

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
driver.navigate.to "http://example.com"

COOKIE_DOMAIN = <<-eotl
var cookieName = arguments[0];
var cookieValue = arguments[1];
var myDate = new Date();
myDate.setMonth(myDate.getMonth() + 12);
document.cookie = cookieName +"=" + encodeURIComponent(cookieValue)
                  + ";expires=" + myDate 
                  + ";domain=.example.com;path=/";
eotl

driver.execute_script(COOKIE_DOMAIN,'test','testvalue')
ap driver.manage.cookie_named('test')
```

Comment: where are credentials being passed in this script?

Comment: you need to call production code/web-service or similar to generate the cookies value by supplying it with the credentials. Ask your developers to provide you such method or open the production code and see it yourself. I did the same thing for the automation tests of the authentication of my company's site.

Comment: my understanding that it should be basic auth, but seems like it is not as other url picking auth credentials within url, just one is not. Thing is that auth will be removed within 2 weeks, for time being execution will be PITA to enter credentials manually for every scenario